# Simple preg expression to strip name into 2 parts based on the space

Tags: php, regex

I have a form field called 'Name' - but I'd like to save the submission into the DB as First Name & Last Name using a preg expression.

Can some illustrate how if I entered the name 'John Smith' into the field a regexp would strip this into First Name - John Surname - Smith

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefer use `split` (version php < 5.3.0) or `explode` which is an alias of `split` function, in your case, you just have to split you fullname with space character `' '`

```
var $fullname = "John Smith";
var $splitfullname = $fullname.split(' ');

var $firstname = $splitfullname[0];
var $lastname = $splitfullname[1];
```

-

```
var $fullname = "John Smith";
var $splitfullname = explode(' ', $fullname);

var $firstname = $splitfullname[0];
var $lastname = $splitfullname[1];
```

if you build the form that catch firstname and fullname, I will suggest you to split your fullname input field into two input field (firstname and lastname).

Comment: That won't work. It looks more like VB or Java rather than PHP. For a start, there is no `split` function in PHP. Next, `explode` takes 2 params - the split char and then the item to split. A `.` will join two strings together rather than call a function of that class (in this case, a String) etc

Comment: @DaveyBoy `Split` function exists ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Comment: and split is obsolete since v5.3.0. My comments regarding the functionality of it still holds though - two params, incorrect use of concatenation etc

Answer (score 2):

For simple cases, you might just want to split the name by blanks:

```
$name = "John Smith";
$nameParts = explode(' ',$name);
var_dump($nameParts);
```

More complex cases (e.g. titles/middle names) might force you to use multiple input fields.

Comment: Definitely have to keep in mind those with "complex" names. Multiple fields in a form might be the best solution to the OP's situation, but I also prefer explode to split strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
$names = explode(" ", $POST['name']);
$firstName = $name[0];
$lastName = $name[1];
```

This is however an absolutely brutal idea. Just make a first name and last name form field. I guarantee at some point someone is going to put something like Alfred E Newman and you're going to end up with their initial or middle name as a last name.

Comment: good point - thanks for the ideas
Gonna use something like this... with some extra logic for people putting in extra words/names etc..

`$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", "Bob E Smith");`

Comment: Why complicate matters? Just use two fields if you want two database entries. It's not going to make it easier for your users and I can almost guarantee it will fail at some point giving you bad data.

Comment: You are 100% right, its an old system so the client doesn't want to add the extra field :(
But you are 1000x times right!! :-) Cheers again

Comment: The client does not want to. Zabs, with all love and beauty, but SO is not for client wishes but for programming questions. Example: The general problem how to split a name into first and lastname has surely been adressed with much more detail on the site before. Search more specifically and you will discover more valuable resources. Also please see [the XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341), we often do not ask for what we want to know. Does not work good with Q&A ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode`:

```
<?php
$fullname='John Smith';

list ($firstName,$lastName)=explode(' ',$fullname);

echo 'First name: '.$firstName.PHP_EOL;
echo 'Last name: '.$lastName.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just created this function just in case someone else has a similar problem - thanks for all of the advice guys!

http://ideone.com/gxvi9